# TreeMap size is always 1 in MapReduce code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to write a code where I am trying to fetch top ten IPAddress that visited the website. I have sample logs and the output of 1st MR code looks like :

```
01-dynamic-c.rotterdam.luna.net 1
01-dynamic-c.wokingham.luna.net 28
02-dynamic-c.wokingham.luna.net 13
03-dynamic-c.wokingham.luna.net 15
04-dynamic-c.rotterdam.luna.net 22
```

Now I want to calculate TopN in 2nd MR job but treemap size is always 1 in mapper . Looks like put operation on treemap keeps replacing my old entry.

```
private TreeMap<Text, Integer> repToRecordMap = new TreeMap<Text, Integer>();
int count = 0;

@Override
public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("key ==> " + key);
    System.out.println("value ==> "
            + Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));
    System.out.println("size ==> " + repToRecordMap.size());

    repToRecordMap.put(key, Integer.parseInt(value.toString()));

}
```

Here is what System.out is printing in logs :

```
key ==> ***.novo.dk
value ==> 16
**size ==> 1**
key ==> 007.thegap.com
value ==> 45
**size ==> 1**
key ==> 01-dynamic-c.rotterdam.luna.net
value ==> 1
**size ==> 1**
```

Every time I have a new key but the size is always 1 that means it keep replacing my old key with new key . Please help me why this is happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the **Text** object into a **String** and define the `Map<String, Integer>`. MapReduce framework reuse when is possible the serializable objects for memory optimization. I think that is what it is happening in your case and the **Text** objects are the same (at object level) even they represent a different **String**.